# Where is user specified data being stored on MacOS

Tags: macos

I install an app .app file to /Applications folder.
Can you please tell me where does the user specified data being stored? How can I do to clean uninstall my application and its user specific data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the application, unfortunately.  Sometimes it is in ~/Library/ folder, though.

Answer (score 0):

[AppTrap](http://konstochvanligasaker.se/apptrap/) should do the trick.

It runs in the background and simply has a preference pane in the System Preferences. Drop the application onto the trash folder and it will ask you whether you want the associated application files to be deleted too.

Comment: This app is outdated and I think it's not doing its job anymore in my Mac. Do you have any new alternatives for it?

Answer (score 0):

Just let the user do that. For instance with [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/).

Otherwise, just give a way in your preferences to reset them. No need to delete the plist file.

Answer (score 0):

[AppDelete](http://www.reggieashworth.com/appdelete) is a free program for uninstalling and cleaning up.

[FSEventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) is a free program for seeing where programs install themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Most information is stored within /Library/, however from time to time you may find applications which store their data within the contents of the .app package itself, or within a subfolder in /Applications/.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea of where to look.

[Where to Put Application Files](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/WhereToPutFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001411-BAJHCHJI)